# Security vulnerabilities in code to insert and return last inserted row number

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have the following code which is supposed to insert a row into a DB table "clicks" (consisting 1 Primary AI column "id" and another column "user" which contains the user's sessions id) upon clicking the Like button. For each user assuming they have a session id set from a login I would like to return to them their most recently inserted id from the table. So the first time the button is clicked it will return 1 etc.
I would like this to be accessible to multiple users through a login system. I was wondering if there are any major security vulnerabilities with my code e.g can the results be forged etc?

index.php:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';
include 'connect.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php       
    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   echo '<a class="like" href="#" onclick="like_add(', $userid,   
  ');">Like</a>';
    ?>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="like.js"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "DB";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

init.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']='1';
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
include 'connect.php';
include 'like.php';
?>
```

like.js:

```
function like_add(userid) {
$.post('like_add.php', {userid:userid}, function(data) {
   if (data == 'success'){
    add_like($userid);
   } else{
       alert(data);
   }
});
}
```

like.php:

```
<?php
function add_like($userid){
include 'connect.php';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clicks (user) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $userid);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT max(id) FROM clicks WHERE user=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($click);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $click;
$stmt->close();
}
?>
```

like_add.php:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';
if (isset($userid)) {
$userid = $userid;
add_like($userid);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add more security: in your connection script. Change the $servername, $username etc to constants. These don’t need to change, and you don’t want them to be changed.

Do you have any type of checks for your sessions? Sessions are more secure than cookies but they can be hijacked in transit when a user logs in. To add some security to your session, use the session_regenerate_id() function when the user logs in, this will generate a new session id therefore if the users id has been hijacked, it is of no use as it will have changed. There are other checks that can be carried out on sessions to secure them but this is a good quick way of adding an extra level.

@nomistic makes some good suggestions also especially regarding encryption of passwords and other sensitive information. Using the crypt() function or PHP’s password hashing API - http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php. Is also a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Your query might give incorrect results if the same user sends multiple requests almost at the same time, case when your query will not return the currently inserted id. You can use the last_insert_id() mysql function which gives you the last inserted auto-increment value, regardless if meanwhile other requests updated the table.

Also, you don't need to pass the user_id parameter with the ajax request, as you anyway can obtain it from the session. Passing the user_id can be considered a security hole, as anyone can modify the onclick handler and trigger clicks for other users. I'd recommend avoiding as much as possible sending user ids in plain text as response.

Comment: sorry to ask so much on here I'm a complete novice. But how can I send the user id when the Like button is clicked otherwise, and what's the correct way to use the last_insert_id?

Comment: Here's the documentation.   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php and here's an easier to read tutorial:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

Comment: When the user successfully logs in to your site, save his user id in session ($_SESSION['user_id'] = $idOfUserThatJustLoggedIn;), and in further requests you'll have it automatically available after calling session_start() (e.g. $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];). As for last inserted id, @nomistic pointed you to the php function to access mysql's last_insert_id() value.

Comment: @nomistic thanks so much, but how can I post this data and get a return without using the onclick method? How can I modify the code to reduce the AJAX vulnerability? I don't understand how to use the insert_id to do so.

Comment: Note, you don't really need that .js to do what you are trying to do.  It can all be handled (and better) with php.   Once you change the other piece it should be fine.  Javascript (in most cases) is better for doing fancy client-side things, but not for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty good on the php side.  You are using session ids for user verification, and have prepared your SQL inserts.   (One question, why are you setting `$_SESSION['user_id']='1'`?  Do you plan on only having one user?  That doesn't seem necessary to me)

However, you might want to tighten up your database-side security.  It's probably a good idea to set up a different user for public database access, and limit the actions on the database side.  For instance, if all they are going to do is `select` or insert, that user should only have access to do so.  I wouldn't use your `root` account for that.  Though it's probably not a huge risk (you are doing pretty well against SQL injection, at least the first two times) just to add another layer is always a good idea.

When dealing with security, it's helpful to think of a "use-case" scenario.  What sort of data are you storing?  Is it something that somebody really would want?   (e.g. is it financial?)   It's always a good idea to look at the human element.   Would someone want to spend more than a day trying to hack your data (is it worth it for them?).

Also, though it's not evident here, you probably want to make sure you have a good form of encrypting passwords.

Another thought: even if it is minor risk, it's not a bad idea to run daily backups, so you can recover your data in a worst-case scenario.

### Edit:

Since it was asked, here's how to setup security at the database side:

First create a new user (following this pattern):

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Granting permissions work like this:

```
 GRANT [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'localhost’;
```

Types of privileges include `ALL PRIVILEGES`, `CREATE`,`DROP`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `GRANT OPTION`.

If you want to read up on this more, here's the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: thanks very much for your help! I want to have multiple users, So user X logs in and clicks the button and is returned click number 84 for example. Also how do I "set up a different user for public database access, and limit the actions on the database side." You are right all they will do is insert and select

Comment: okay, sure.   I edited it above and provided some information on creating a user and permissions.

Comment: also, please note the comments below about passing the user_id as a possible security hole in the AJAX;  it's best to handle it with insert_id in the php.